# Customizing Style&Template of a wpf user control from another assembly

Tags: c#, wpf, templates, dll, styles

I have a separate solution in which I want to create a User Control Library that I can reference as a dll in other projects (so use just the dll, without xaml+code behind).

For example, I can have such a control:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfUserControlsLibrary.PlayerControls"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="btnPlayer" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="100"/>
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="50"/>
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button Style="{StaticResource btnPlayer}" Name="btnPlay" Click="btnPlay_Click">Play</Button>
        <Button Style="{StaticResource btnPlayer}" Name="btnStop" Click="btnStop_Click">Stop</Button>
        <Button Style="{StaticResource btnPlayer}" Name="btnPause" Click="btnPause_Click">Pause</Button>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

For the code above, let's say there is another solution TestUI that references the WpfUserControlsLibrary's dll and I would like the following:

- use the default style for the buttons
- if the TestUI has a custom look and feel, I want to be able to change the default style of the buttons, by defining or inheriting TestUI resources (I don't know yet if this part can be done or how)

Is there any way of declaring this control or defining its style/template so that its UI could be customized from another project that references this dll (and meanwhile keep the code-behind functionality)?

Answer (score 1):

In you App.xaml file, add the Resource file as a MergedDictionary.

Since you're getting from another assembly, check out the proper way to reference it at [MSDN - Pack URIs in WPF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa970069%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

I'm using it at my current project!
Your code should look something like this:

```
<ResourceDictionary>
   <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
      <ResourceDictionary Source="myresourcedictionary.xaml"/>
      <ResourceDictionary Source="myresourcedictionary2.xaml"/>
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary>
```